# How to add one more function to run

Tags: javascript

I use the method below so that when the user clicks the button, it goes to the link `http://example.com` and also runs the `function()`, it works fine.

**Script**

```
function () 
{
.....
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a href="http://example.com" onclick="function()"></a>
```

Now I would like to add one more function to this button, when click it, it also should run another link eg. `http://yyy.com`  (the reason to run this link is to delete something, as this link can do deleting).

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can call window.open in your funciton in order to open yyy.com

Answer (score 1):

Use `window.open` method to open other addresses.

**HTML**

```
<a href=""ss.com" onclick="movee()"></a>
```

**script**

```
function movee()
{
window.open="xxxdd.com"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this ...   [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HGy3f/)

```
<a href="http://www.microsoft.com" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com'); window.open('http://www.yahoo.com');">Click Here</a>
```